# Integrated Integrals

Tags: integration

We are asked to compute the double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{1}^{2}y\sin(xy)dxdy$$

Integrating with respect to $x$ gives:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}-\cos(xy)\bigg|_{x=1}^{x=2}dy$$

I used $u$ substitution to arrive at the above. Hence, I replaced my limits of integration with $\frac{1}{y}$ and $\frac{2}{y}$. But the answer leaves the limits of integration at $x=1,x=2$. Why?

Also if someone could help me integrate $sin(xy)$ with respect to $y$ that would help when reversing the order (switching $dy$ with $dx$ and therefore the limits of integration).

Comment: $\int y\sin(xy)\,dx=-\cos(xy) +C$ with or without substitutions. Therefore limits of integration doesn't change

Comment: Of course. I am too use to using u-substitution I perhaps was just confused.

Comment: Perhaps you could show the integration by parts solution for $\sin(xy)$ with respect to $y$

Comment: Use the same substitution

Comment: Recalling LIATE I would substitute algebra first. But there is no algebra? Is $u=dy$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's integrate w.r.t. $y$:
$$
\int y\sin(xy)\,dy\stackrel{u=xy}{=} \int \frac{u}{x}\sin u\frac{du}{x} = \frac1{x^2} \int u\sin u\,du = \frac1{x^2}(\sin u - u\cos u)+C=\frac1{x^2}(\sin(xy) - xy\cos(xy))+C
$$
and
$$
\int_0^\pi y\sin(xy)\,dy = \frac1{x^2}\left.(\sin(xy) - xy\cos(xy))\right|_{y=0}^{y=\pi}=\frac1{x^2}(\sin{\pi x}-\pi x\cos(\pi x))
$$
And now integrate w.r.t. $x$:
$$
\int_1^2 dx\int_0^\pi y\sin(xy)\,dy=\int_1^2 \frac{dx}{x^2}(\sin{\pi x}-\pi x\cos(\pi x))=-\frac{\sin{\pi x}}{x}\Big|_{x=1}^{x=2}=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Work the inner integral first $\int _{1}^{2}\ y*sin ( xy) dx$, treat y as a constant here, with a simple u-substitution.

Then you should get $-cos(2y) + cos(y)$
Integrate that from 0 to $\pi$.

Comment: Of course. Integrating with respect to $x$ for this particular problem is particularly easy.